# Add onClick function in Ext.XTemplate to specific inner element

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have a list and i created the itemTpl config as "Ext.XTemplate" object, and i can make a listener to the list items but i can not specify the onClick for a specific element in the "Ext.XTemplate", every time the click of the whole list item work instead of the inner element onClick, i tried this but also did not work properly

```
{
 xtype: 'list',
 reference: 'goodsList',
 scrollable: 'y',
 itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                "<div class='goods-item'> " +
                "<span class='goods-info'> {countryOfOrigin} - {valueOfOrigin} - {valueInQar} </span>" +
                "<button class='goods-btn' onclick={[this.onDelete(values.id)]}> Delete </button> </div> "
                ,
                {
                    onDelete: function (value) {
                        alert(value);
                    }
                }
            ),
 listeners: {
                itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
            },
 itemHeight: '50px',
 items: []
}
```

Comment: if you can share a fiddle, i can help you. https://fiddle.sencha.com/